# Get value for custom options

Tags: custom-options

I'm for my simple product added dropdown custom options. Now i want set default value in dropdown (one, two, three, four, five), defauld value should be: five and on default display also in checkout and ordrer rewiew. How i can do this better?

Thanks

Comment: Do you mean custom product attributes, right?

Comment: yes, right, need set and get default value custom product options

Comment: Where you need these attributes to be displayed and why?